# Distance of antipodal points on small Riemannian spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetry, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $p \in M$.

Is it true that for sufficiently small $r>0$, for any $v \in T_pM$ with norm $|v|_g=r$,
$$
d_g(\exp_p(v),\exp_p(-v))=2r
$$
holds?

I have an argument (below) that shows that this holds **for at least one such $v$** with norm $r$.

We claerly have $d_g(\exp_p(v),\exp_p(-v)) \le2r$ by triangle inequality.

I thought using the existence of convex neighbourhoods but so far without luck.

---

Here is an almost(?) rigorous argument for the **existence** of such a $v$;

Let $S_r(p) \subseteq M$ be the sphere of radius $r$ around $p$.

Let $q=\exp_p(w),q'=\exp_p(w')$ be points such that
$$
\text{diam}(S_r(p))=d_g(q,q').
$$

Let $\gamma$ be a minimizing geodesic between $q,q'$. Then $\gamma$ is orthogonal to $S_r(p)$ at $q,q'$, i.e. if $\gamma(0)=q, \gamma(L)=q'$, then
$$
\dot \gamma(0) \perp T_qS_r(p), \,\,\,\,\dot \gamma(L) \perp T_{q'}S_r(p).
$$
This implies that $\dot \gamma(0)$ is in the direction of the unique geodesic from $q$ to $p$ (the "backwards" of the radial geodesic $p \to q$), and similarly, $\dot \gamma(L)$ is in the direction of the unique geodesic from $q'$ to $p$.

So, $\gamma$ passes through $p$, and we have
$$
d_g(q,q')=d_g(q,p)+d_g(p,q')=2r
$$
as required.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but these two points are joined by an obvious geodesic of length 2r and on a small enough neighborhood, any short geodesic is minimal.

Comment: For $r$ small enough, geodesic segment contained in a ball of radius $r$ are minimizing. As @Thorgott pointed out, $\gamma(t) = \exp_p((-1+2t)v)$ is an obvious geodesic segment.

Comment: @Didier Thanks, you are both right, I think. However, some care is needed I think. If I am not mistaken, we need the concept of "totally normal neighbourhood" around each point, to make this rigorous. You may see my answer below. Is there an easier approach?

Comment: @Thorgott  Thanks, please see my comment above.

Comment: @AsafShachar You are right, some care is needed. When I said "for $r$ small enough", I implicitely refered to normal neighbourhood

Comment: Specifically, we need a neighbourhood which is normal w.r.t each of its points, not just the center of the ball $p$.

Comment: @AsafShachar in your argument I think you cannot exclude the case when the minimizing geodesic from $q$ to $q’$ is not contained in the geodesic ball around $p$. This happens, for instance, in a geodesic ball of radius $>\pi/2$ in the unit round sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a second thought, I think that the result follows from the existence of what is called "totally normal neighbourhoods".

Specifically, there exists an open set $W$ containing $p$ and $\delta>0$, such that for every $q \in W$, $\exp_q$ is a diffeomorphism on $B_{\delta}(0) \subset T_qM$, and $W \subseteq \exp_q(B_{\delta}(0))$.

Now, take $0<r< \delta/2$, and let $q=\exp_p(v),q'=\exp_p(-v)\in S_r(p) \subset W$. Then
$q'=\exp_q(w)$ for a **unique** $w \in B_{\delta}(0) \subset T_qM$, and $$d_g(q,q')=|w|.$$

However, we already have a candidate for $w$:

If $\gamma:[0,1] \to M$ is the geodesic from $p$ to $q$, i.e. $\gamma(t)=\exp_p(tv)$, then $w=-2\dot \gamma (1)$. So, $$|w|=2|\dot \gamma (1)|=2|\dot \gamma (0)|=2|v|=2r.$$

Thus $d_g(q,q')=2r$ as required.